# Can one define a Java class purely with a Spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I'm curious as to whether one can define a Java class purely using a Spring configuration, and then probably create a bean from it too.

I.e, usually one would have

```
<bean id="mybean" class="com.my.existing.Klass" />
```

But this means you would need a Klass.java file that defines this class. Is it possible to give a bean a fully qualified class name and define its getters and setters using properties (so that this class is generated during compile time or something)?

UPDATE:

I decided to provide an example. Assume you have a simple struct that is essentially just a data carrier:

```
class Person {
  public String name;
  public Long id;

  public Person(String name, Long id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
  } 
}
```

To instantiate this using Spring, you would have:

```
<bean id="somePerson" class="mypackage.Person">
  <property id="name" value="John Smith" />
  <property id="id" value="1234" />
</bean>
```

If you wanted to make changes to this structure, you have to do it in two places. What if you can simply generate the class from the XML? Sure, it might require some extra info such as the classes to use for the properties, but that could be provided as an attribute.

Comment: For what purpose?  What would you use it for?

Comment: PropertyHolder, so a HashMap like object is possible as bean.

Comment: Simple beans - structs essentially. I.e. define the class using a xml bean definition and simply reference it in your code.

Comment: Spring is a DI container, not class-builder and so one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean is what you are looking for, it is not Spring.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about a DynaBean! It certainly sounds interesting (though doesn't completely fit the idea I had in mind).

Comment: P.S. this gave me a great way to solve the problem in a different way :) I'm going to consider it the best answer, even though it doesn't directly address the question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you might be interested in [Dynamic language support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html) in [spring](/questions/tagged/spring).  Here an example in [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy):

```
<lang:groovy id="messenger">
    <lang:inline-script>
        package org.springframework.scripting.groovy;

        import org.springframework.scripting.Messenger

        class GroovyMessenger implements Messenger {

            String message
        }
    </lang:inline-script>
    <lang:property name="message" value="I Can Do The Frug" />
</lang:groovy>
```

You can also reference external `.groovy` file and even auto-refresh changes in it. Spring pports [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy), [jruby](/questions/tagged/jruby) and [beanshell](/questions/tagged/beanshell). A while back I also wrote [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [support](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2010/09/javascript-dynamic-language-support-in.html).

Comment: This looks neat, but if I'm going to write Java code I might as well just create a Java class file :) I was thinking more along the lines of using the already existing spring XML syntax

Answer (score 1):

Seems someone really likes xml. Maybe instead of trying to fit simple classes in xml why not take a look at annotation configuration and java configuration and remove the need for xml entirely (see [Java Config](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java))

Comment: Worthy consideration, though a big portion of the stack is already wired together using Spring - it would mean that I end up having a split configuration.